# Split View Controller and Segue Unwind

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `UISplitViewController` scheme for my project, and I put a `UITableViewController` in `DetailedView`. So there are two tables on left side (navigation) and right side (content).

Then I've created a new `UIViewController` and created a segue (Show Detail) from `UITableViewController` in `DetailedView` to navigate to this VC. I've also added and Unwind Segue for `UIViewController` to navigate back to `UITableViewController` in `DetailedView`.

But unwind segue doesn't works, because I'm presenting `UIViewController` segue as Show Detail segue. When I change segue to Modal Segue unwind works correctly, but I'm losing `UISplitViewController` (navigation master side disappears).

Do you have any ideas to make Unwind Segue work and return to Detailed View?

Comment: @matt Show also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using UISplitViewController scheme for my project, and I put a UITableViewController in DetailedView.

If that's literally true, it's wrong. The correct architecture, which is what you are given by the Master-Detail template, is:

```
UISplitViewController
    UINavigationController [master]
        UITableVieController
    UINavigationController [detail]
        SomeUIViewController
```

So your UITableViewController goes where I've written "SomeUIViewController". To navigate from there within the detail view, just `push` (or `show`). The user can now navigate back with the Back button, or you can `pop` in code.

Comment: Thank you, Matt for your answer! Using native navigation of `UISplitViewController`!

Comment: yep sounds like the OP is missing the detail navigation controller